# Use DBMS_CRYPTO to encrypt data

Tags: plsql

I'm currently using Oracle 10g. I use DBMS_CRYPTO package to encrypt the passwords of users for login. In order to encrypt or decrypt the data, I must have a key. So where should I put the key in order to hide it from other developers, or is there another way to  encrypt data without being able to decrypt back?

In SQL Server, I just use PWDENCRYPT function to encrypt, and when I want to compare the data entered by the users correct or not, I use PWDCOMPARE. Pls advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

To hide the key from other developers, hopefully this article will be helpful, it includes a section on key management:

http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/05-jan/o15security.html

To encrypt data without being able to decrypt it back, you may wish to look into [*one way hashes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).  Oracle provides this in the form of DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH, which is simple to use (as discussed [here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=347102)):

```
SQL> select SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH('FFFFFF',1) from dual;
7D91F6D9BE28A9756B0D2F11D3AF4F0C
```

You then store only the hash in the database - you can verify the password if hashing the user input matches your stored hash, but you cannot retrieve the password in any way.